# why this code enter two entries into the database

Tags: asp.net, mysql

i have a code that retrieve some content and enter it the database :

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"connection string");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO copy (id) VALUES ('" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "')", conn);
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO copy (cv) VALUES ('" + mainEditor.Content.Replace("'", "''") + "')",conn);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
```

**it connects and enters the data fine but it enters the data in two not one (it creates two rows instead of one)**

*i am using asp.net 3.5 and mysql 5.0*
what am i doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because two separate inserts are running.  You can insert more than one value, try this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO copy (id, cv) VALUES ('" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "', '" + mainEditor.Content.Replace("'", "''") + "')", conn);
```

You can comma separate the fields, and the values so it inserts into one record.  Executing 2 insert commands will always create 2 records.

Answer (score 3):

It's inserting two rows because you're executing two `INSERT` statements. Each time you run an `INSERT` it does just that: inserts a row.

I'm guessing you wanted to create a single row with both the `id` and `cv` fields populated. The SQL syntax for that is `INSERT INTO copy (id, cv) VALUES ('x', 'y');`

So:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO copy (id) VALUES ('" + Page.User.Identity.Name + "', '" + mainEditor.Content.Replace("'", "''") + "')",conn);
```

Comment: If they must be separate you can run one INSERT statement then run an UPDATE statement

Comment: It sounds like `id` is either a `PRIMARY KEY` or is defined as `UNIQUE`. In either case, you cannot insert more than one row with the same value for that field, and you already have a row with `0` there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which driver you're using so I'll use the documentation I found for [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/).  I would try to use something along these lines (explanation of code below)

```
using( var conn = new MySqlConnection(@"connection string"))
using( cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn) ){

    cmd.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO copy (id, cv) 
        VALUES (:name, :userContent)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlType.[correct type]]).Value = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("userContent", MySqlType.[correct type], [column size]).Value = mainEditor.Content;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

The use of the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) construct is because [MySqlConnection](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.html) and [MySqlCommand](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.html) classes both implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface so they need to be disposed of when you're done using them to avoid possible resource leaks.

The `:name` and `:userContent` is what I found in documentation for creating [parametrized queries](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html#parambasics).  This will allow the database driver to take care of escaping all of the special characters out of user input to avoid SQL injection attacks.  This part is actually really important, there are some REALLY sophisticated SQL injection attacks out there, so there's a good chance simply escaping `'` (as you were doing) isn't enough.